# How to use VBA to change a date in SQL query in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need help if it is possible where I can upload SQL query in excel via Get Data>From Database>From SQL Server Database, and be able to change the date in this uploaded SQL query.
My hope is to use three cells within tab where i enter a date, and either use a vba or SQL looks cell value automatically and provide results when i refresh SQL.

Right now i have these sets of dates.

```
set @eomdate = '2022-10-31'
set @startdate = '2016-01-01'
set @enddate = '2022-10-31'
```

I want to use cells in excel that lookup date entered in cell A1, B1, and C1. My goal is to change the dates to get results based on dates entered.

```
set @eomdate = Sheet1A1
set @startdate = Sheet1B1
set @enddate = Sheet1C1
```

is there a way to use a VBA code that will change the dates based on cells mentioned above? I am researching but have been unlucky.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Query1")
`ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Kosta

This is the first time I am trying to do this but I am hoping that when I enter a date in cell A1, and i run a vba CommandButton1, the SQL that was uploaded in excel, will change the date prior running the SQL query.